# How do I show that $\frac {\cos^2 A}{\cos^2 B} + \frac {\cos^2 B}{\cos^2 C} + \frac {\cos^2 C}{\cos^2 A} \ge 4(\cos^2 A + \cos^2 B + \cos^2 C)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inequality, fractions, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Let $A, B, C$ be the angles of an acute triangle. Show that $$\frac {\cos^2 A}{\cos^2 B} + \frac {\cos^2 B}{\cos^2 C} + \frac {\cos^2 C}{\cos^2 A} \ge 4(\cos^2 A + \cos^2 B + \cos^2 C).$$

How should I approach this kind of "geometric inequalities"? I've considered substituting the cosines using the law of the cosines and then use the Ravi transformation to turn it into an algebraic one, but that seems too tedious and unlikely to yield any beautiful solution. Any hints will be appreciated!

Comment: why are these two inequalities are different?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Sorry. I'll edit it.

Comment: try the theorem of cosines!

Comment: from where does this inequality come?

Comment: are you sure that this inequality is true?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner It comes from a math competition, so it must true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By AM-GM easy to show that $\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{z}+\frac{z}{x}\geq\frac{x+y+z}{\sqrt[3]{xyz}}$ for all positives $x$, $y$ and $z$ and

$\cos\alpha\cos\beta\cos\gamma\leq\frac{1}{8}$.

Hence, $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{\cos^2\alpha}{\cos^2\beta}\geq\frac{\cos^2\alpha+\cos^2\beta+\cos^2\gamma}{\sqrt[3]{\cos^2\alpha\cos^2\beta\cos^2\gamma}}\geq4\left(\cos^2\alpha+\cos^2\beta+\cos^2\gamma\right)$. Done!

Comment: Excellent answer! Can you explain why $\cos A \cos B \cos C \le \frac 18$ and possibly how you came up with this solution?

Comment: There are very many ways to proof. For example, $\cos\alpha\left(\cos(\beta-\gamma)-\cos\alpha\right)\leq\frac{1}{4}$ or $\left(\cos\alpha-\frac{1}{2}\cos(\beta-\gamma)\right)^2+\frac{1}{4}\sin^2(\beta-\gamma)\geq0$.